# ASP.NET MVC 403 Forbidden - error resulting in unexpected behaviour randomly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

We make an Ajax call to a URL within our application root and it works perfectly on localhost but also an existing published production site. But for some reason having the same URL with a different port number results in the 403 for one of the sites.

[image]

```
https://acmesite.com:55555/Plain/ColorCodeSchedule?scheduleID=175&entitytype=0
```

The above call works perfectly every time.

```
https://acmesite.com:55500/Plain/ColorCodeSchedule?scheduleID=175&entitytype=0
```

This one results in the error....

The source code is in separate applications with separate application pools but the app assemblies are similar in that the codebase is the same although they run on the same IIS web server.

Is there a chance that the route config is mapping to an invalid (similar) path because these sites are hosted on the same machine?

Below is the very basic route config:

```
Public Module RouteConfig
    Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

        routes.MapRoute(
            name:="Default",
            url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        )
    End Sub
End Module
```